# Best practice: A class which represents a single database table

Tags: php, oop

I have an user database table containing fields like: id, username, password, email, roles, the password restore token and expiration and so on.

Now I need a class to read and write user data.

Is it better to create class variables for each database field and read/write from/to them like this:

```
class User {
    private $db;
    private $user_id;
    private $username;
    private $email;

    [...]

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($name) {
        $this->username = $name;
    }

    public function readDB() {
         $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", 
         array((int)$this->user_id));
         $user = $sth->fetch();
         if($user !== false && is_array($user)) {
             $this->username = $user['username'];
             $this->email = $user['email'];
             [...]
    }

    public function writeDB() {
        [...]
        $this->db->insert('users', array(
            'username' => $this->username
            'email' => $this->email), array('user_id' => $this->user_id)); 
    }
}
```

Or go without class variables and do it like this:

```
class User {
    private $db;

    [...]

    public function readDB($userID) {
         $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", 
         array((int)$userID));
         $user = $sth->fetch();
         return $user;
    }

    public function writeDB($userID, $username, $email ...) {
        $this->db->insert('users', array(
            'username' => $username
            'email' => $email), array('user_id' => $userID)); 
    }
}
```

I don't see the advantages of the first solution, except it would be easy to change the database field names later, but that could be easily done with a simple change in the lower readDB version.

The disadvantages of the first version are, that I need to write a lot of get and set methods and the method calls need a little bit more processing time and I have to check each class variable first, whether it was already set before inserting/updating the data. The second version would automatically produce a method argument error if an argument is missing.

Sometimes I need for example just the email address of an user and the first version would always need to read all fields from database first and then call the getEmail method. The second approach would allow to write a special method for returning single database fields (SELECT email FROM user WHERE user_id = ?). This would reduce database load.

Which way do you prefer and why?

Comment: first approach violates S from SOLID (User class is DTO and DAO at the same time), 2nd approach violates O from SOLID (it returns array which is open for modification and closed for extension)

Comment: Your first approach is on a good track but you will want to remove the work of getting the data from your Entity. Creating a database class that does your Persistence and data access is a good option. Or find yourself a good old fashion Database framework. There are plenty to choose from and all have their own special awesomeness and pain points.

Comment: I'm using Doctrine DBAL because of very lightweight overhead. This class should be only for reading and saving data of the user database table in combination with an user administration tool. All other logic is handled by the security provider.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the domain entity logic from the persistence logic. Do not have a single class, that contains it all, because then you basically end up with glorified version of [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) anti-pattern.

A much better option is to have [domain object](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject) dealing with the business logic (things like validation and data transformations) and leave the storage logic in a separate [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) instance.

In practice that code looks kinda like this:

```
$user = new Entity\User;
$user->setUsername('Drunk Lizard');

$mapper = new Mapper\User($pdo);
$mapper->fetch($user);

if (!$user->hasStatus(Entity\User::UNVERIFIED)) {
    throw new InvalidAction;
}

if (!$user->hasToken($request->get('token'))) {
    throw new WrongToken;
}

$user->setStatus(Entity\User::VERIFIED);
$mapper->store($user);
```

Comment: This is already some kind of data mapper class, just for the database action. The user entity is handled by the security provider of Silex/Symfony.